# How to use insert and update query with in the same stored procedure using mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In my project i'm using stored procedure. Here i already wrote query for inserting the data. That is,

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_studentdetails`(
in inputStream mediumblob,
in salutation varchar(50),
in fname varchar(50),
in mname varchar(50),
in lname varchar(50),
in dob varchar(50),
in gender varchar(50),
in identify varchar(50),
in nationality varchar(50),
in blood varchar(50),
in physical varchar(50),
in health varchar(50),
in nationalid varchar(50),
in mtongue varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO 
tbl_student_details(studentpic,salutation,fname,mname,lname,
dob,gender,identify,nationality,blood,physical,health,nationalid,mtongue)
values (inputStream,salutation,fname,mname,lname,
dob,gender,identify,nationality,blood,physical,health,nationalid,mtongue);
END
```

Here I want to add one more update query for this same table. I don't know how to do.

Comment: What do you want the update query to do? Do you want it run instead of the insert if the student already exists?

Comment: No No dear JeffUK. Actually in my table<tbl_student_details> i have 20 fields/columns. When i insert the student data through insert query i just passing 14 parameters. After that i  have to add further fields for that same row with the use of update query. How to add that update query with in the same procedure?

Comment: Just write it afterwards, stored procedures will run multiple statements (separated by semi-colons).  Why do you not just insert all of the columns at the same time though, you can get the 14 values from the parameters and the other values from somewhere else.

Comment: Yes u are right i understood what u are asking, but as per my convenience i just split the UI page in 2 jsp files. from the first file it has 14 fields only. So i just insert that 14 data into database table. and then i go the next page, It has 6 fields. Similarly i add this 6 data following from the 15th position for the same row using update query . It's working perfectly but i'm struggling how to do it with in the single stored procedure?

Comment: If you have two different pages, and two distinct interactions (Create new Student, add additional information for student) then I don't think doing it with one SP would be necessary.

Comment: ohhhh kk. i'll try dear JeffUK. Thanks for ur good response till now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;
```

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

of course you have to build it for you procedure

In your case this should look like

```
INSERT INTO 
    tbl_student_details
        (
          studentpic,salutation,fname,mname,lname,
          dob,gender,identify,nationality,blood,physical,
          health,nationalid,mtongue
        )
    values 
        (
          inputStream,salutation,fname,mname,lname,
          dob,gender,identify,nationality,blood,physical,
          health,nationalid,mtongue
        )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        (
          studentpic=inputStream,salutation=salutation,fname=fname,....
          -- go with rest of your variables...
          -- you should consider to use diffrent name or quote them right
        );
```

Here for you need some unique columns in your db that causes the duplicate effekt. And you may add a ID column as primary key to your create.

Edit: According to your comment

It's still the same thing you do... you will update existing data, including new data for this row or only new data when you can seperate it.

E.g.

```
insert into tbl(a,b,c) values ('aaa','bbb','ccc') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE b='bbb', c='ccc', d='ddd', e='eee', f='fff';
```

Comment: Yes dear Dwza ! u almost came to my point. in my table i have fields like tbl(a,b,c,d,e,f). I already inserted tbl(a,b,c). Now i want to insert further data like tbl(d,e,f) for that same row, with the use of update query how to do?